# @RequestMapping not working with no exception

Tags: spring

I have a class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class LoginController {


 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getLoginPage(@RequestParam(value="error", required=false) boolean error, 
   ModelMap model) {

}

}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
                classpath:META-INF/spring-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

appcontext.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="mysrc.src"/>
```

spring servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="mysrc.src"/>

           <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

I WAS getting an error like "no mapping found in dispatcher blah blah"

But NOW i can see no exception on console.

I only see 404

```
http://localhost:9090/app/auth/login
```

I put breakpoint in getLoginPage method in debug mode but no flow.

Beside suggestions i want to ask how can i be sure abour Spring has scanned an realised my @RequestMapping class? Searching on starting up console maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when you get a 404 with no error message from Spring, it usually means your app is deployed under a different context than you are expecting.  For example, your code sample indicates you are deploying your webapp to /, are you sure thats where its being deployed?  Are you using tomcat?  If so, your webapp should be named ROOT.war.  Can you provide more details like where/how you are deploying your webapp and maybe the web.xml as well?

As far as your mappings go, Spring will log which controllers it scanned along with their request path at the INFO logging level.  The dispatcher servlet will give always you an error message if it cannot match your request to a controller, so no error message indicates to me your requests are not going through the dispatcher servlet.

Comment: I am building the source in Eclipse and clean Tomcat in Eclipse. I can not found myapp named dir under Tomcat/webapps. I think you are right about dispatcher servlet is not aware of my requests. because when i deleted my LoginController from source clean-build everything, dispatcher still do not tell that it can not found something. Then, how can i make dispatcher servlet to know about my reuqest. Thanks.

Comment: my controller's constructor is running during server start up. then, how can i make dispatcher servlet to know about my request?

Answer (score 1):

Your request mapping is looking right.

You can create an constructor to your controller and put a log statement or a break point there to see if the controller is created by spring.

Note that your component-scan would also initialize the controller twice (once for appcontext.xml and once for servlet.xml). You should add filters to make sure controllers are only created from the servlet.xml:

appcontext.xml (everything except controllers):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z">
  <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>
```

servlet.xml (only controllers):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z" use-default-filters="false">
  <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

And just to be sure: The `base-package` attribute of `component-scan` has to be a valid java package and not a path to your src directory (`mysrc.src` looks a bit like your src folder ;-) )

Comment: Your information seems very valuable. When i available to test with your info i am going tell the result. Thanks.